# Can I use browser's website code to recreate a website by my own way(change design, etc)?

Tags: web

For example, we have a cool styled website, can we use developer options(f12) from browser to snatch this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring any legal / copyright implications, you can grab the **client**-side code this way, yes. All HTML, CSS, JavaScript and imagery can be seen through the **[F12 Developer Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/gg589512(v=vs.85))**.

However, there is no way to know what **server**-side code a website is using (outside of the server owner themselves configuring something incorrectly and thereby exposing that information).

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [Obsidian Age](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2341603/obsidian-age) is a good one. I'm going to add some more information that may be useful to you.

I've used this technique myself of getting source code via the developer window. Usually I want to find out how they did some neat CSS or JS trick so that I can try it in my own apps.

The files that make up a website such as HTML, JavaScript, and CSS you can find in the Network tab and can easily copy these.

However you should know the JS, CSS, and even (sometimes to a degree) the HTML files have been minimized and are typically missing any comments from the original developers. Chrome has a nice feature that will un-compress JS files and you can even set break points and step through the JS code.